# md date picker with out day view option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I want to show my date-picker with out date view just like credit card expire view 
For this i am following the below code but after selecting the month and view i am getting into the date view of the selected month....how to overcome this

```js
angular.module('datepickerBasicUsage', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
  var monthFormat = buildLocaleProvider("MMM-YYYY");
   function buildLocaleProvider(formatString) {
    return {
      formatDate: function(date) {
        if (date) return moment(date).format(formatString);
        else return null;
      },
      parseDate: function(dateString) {
        if (dateString) {
          var m = moment(dateString, formatString, true);
          return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
        } else return null;
      }
    };
  }


  $scope.dateFields = {
    type: 'date',
    required: false,
    binding: 'applicant.expectedGraduation',
    //startView: 'month',
    label: 'Credit Card Expiry - Year/Month picker',
    locale: monthFormat
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="datepickerBasicUsage">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.3/angular-material.css">
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style='padding: 40px;'>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="dateFields.selectedDate"
                     ng-required="dateFields.required"
                     md-date-locale="dateFields.locale"
                     md-current-view="year"
                     md-open-on-focus="true">
        </md-datepicker>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [this](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9260) issue is for the feature you described. Sadly, that isn't in any of the current versions for now it seems

Comment: then how can i achive this ??and the issue is using someother cdn which is not provided by standard like google apis

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to get that behavior from their official library until they roll out this feature in some next version.. though you can use any forked ones if you want

Comment: no i can't'do that becase some of my other functionalities are breaking up if gone through that cdn

Comment: bad luck then! try to find any third-party datepicker for material which can support this feature and is popular enough!

Comment: okay i will try to find something and let me know if you found anything and thanks for your time